# jQuery toggle hidden so fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, toggle

I want to use jQuery hover()+toggle() for my "mega menu"

there are my basic structure

I feel the toggle to hidden too fast?

because I can't click the google like in the demo "A content"

**

```js
$(function() {
    $(".sub_menu").hide();
    $("#menuA").hover(function() {
        $("#menuA_submenu").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu li {
  flex:1;
  background:#f35;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:1rem;
}

.content{
  display:none;
  background:#fcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menuA"><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li id="menuB"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li id="menuC"><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="content" id="menuA_submenu">A content
  <hr>
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a></div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">B content</div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">C content</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**

Comment: the problem is not because of hidden is too fast , its because you remove mouse from the element #menuA and its called hover destroy you can insert the div element inside the li and this will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your ultimate goal? How do you hope to present the picture?

Hover $("#menuA") than $("#menuA_submenu") will be displayed.
The cursor has left $("#menuA") before entering $("#menuA_submenu"), so it is no longer hovered.

Suggest a few solutions:

1. Submenu must be seamless with the menu item.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".sub_menu").hide();
    $("#menuA, #menuA_submenu").hover(function() {
        $("#menuA_submenu").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  margin-bottom: 0;  /*new*/
}

.menu li {
  flex:1;
  background:#f35;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;  /*new*/
}

.content{
  display:none;
  background:#fcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Examples</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menuA"><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li id="menuB"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li id="menuC"><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>  
  <div class="content" id="menuA_submenu">A content
   <hr>
 <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">B content</div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">C content</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

2. Change hover to click trigger.

   $(function() {

   ```
   $(".sub_menu").hide();

   $("#menuA").click(function() {

       $("#menuA_submenu").toggle();

   });
   ```

   });
3. When hover, display the corresponding submenu until hover to other buttons. (Each hover behavior can be merged into one.)

   $(function() {

   ```
   $(".sub_menu").hide();

   $("#menuA").mouseenter(function() {

       $(".content").hide();

       $("#menuA_submenu").show();

   });

   $("#menuB").mouseenter(function() {

       $(".content").hide();

       $("#menuB_submenu").show();

   });
   ```

   });

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try add param to toggle function

```
$("#menuA_submenu").toggle(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this :

```js
$(function() {
    $(".sub_menu").hide();
    $("#menuA , .content").hover(function() {
        $("#menuA_submenu").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu li {
  flex:1;
  background:#f35;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:1rem;
}

.content{
  display:none;
  background:#fcc;
  margin-top:-32px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menuA"><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li id="menuB"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li id="menuC"><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="content" id="menuA_submenu">A content
  <hr>
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a></div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">B content</div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">C content</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `slideToggle('slow')` like this,

```js
$(function() {
    $(".sub_menu").hide();
    $("#menuA").hover(function() {
        $("#menuA_submenu").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu li {
  flex:1;
  background:#f35;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:1rem;
}

.content{
  display:none;
  background:#fcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menuA"><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li id="menuB"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li id="menuC"><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="content" id="menuA_submenu">A content
  <hr>
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a></div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">B content</div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">C content</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var thetimeout;
  $('#menuA,.content').mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(thetimeout);
    $('#menuA_submenu').slideDown();
  });
  $('#menuA,.content').mouseleave(function() {
    thetimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#menuA_submenu').slideUp();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  flex: 1;
  background: #f35;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menuA"><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li id="menuB"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li id="menuC"><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="content" id="menuA_submenu">A content
    <hr>
    <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">B content</div>
  <div class="content" id="menuB_submenu">C content</div>

</body>

</html>
```